# How to ORDER by the ratio of two SUM/COUNTs in a SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

In a `SELECT` query as

```
SELECT 
category_id, 
COUNT(*) AS Total, 
SUM(IF(year=2016,1,0) AS year2016, 
SUM(IF(year=2015,1,0) AS year2015
FROM articles
GROUP BY category_id
```

How can I `ORDER BY` the ratio of `year2016/year2015`?

Comment: `ORDER BY SUM(IF(year=2016,1,0)/SUM(IF(year=2015,1,0) DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the `SELECT` statement into a sub-query will allow you to re-use the calculated `SUM` aggregates.  Casting to a `DECIMAL` will tell MySQL not to use integer division and to keep values to the right of the decimal point.

```
SELECT category_id, Total, year2016, year2015
FROM
  (SELECT 
    category_id, 
    COUNT(*) AS Total, 
    SUM(IF(year=2016,1,0)) AS year2016, 
    SUM(IF(year=2015,1,0)) AS year2015
  FROM articles
  GROUP BY category_id) AS t
ORDER BY CAST(year2016 AS DECIMAL(14,4)) / CAST(year2015 AS DECIMAL(14,4))
```